# How to edit value of product quantity using sanity (next.js)?

Tags: next.js, comments, product, sanity, product-quantity

I have a problem, I need to change the product quantity value. When a customer creates a new order, I need to change the quantity of the product in stock from the order, but I don't know how I can change the value in sanity using the code.

I tried to find a solution on the internet, but I couldn't find anything. I only found how to create comments (it's similar), but not how to edit comments.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution just add this code `client.patch(docID).dec({quantity: 1}).commit()` (https://www.sanity.io/schemas/mutate-set-or-change-values-deep-within-documents-psPXQ26_wA_i).

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it solves your problem.